# JRE compliance level mismatch between Workspace and New Project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a newly installed Eclipse instance and need to use recent Java features. I have changed compliance to 1.7 (through *Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Java*):

[image]

When I create a new Java project, if I select "Use a project specific JRE" I get a compliance warning:

[image]

If I opt for the default JRE I get a similar message, but this time telling me the workspace is using a 1.4 JRE:

[image]

What is causing these messages? If the in the *Preferences* compliance is set to to 1.7, why is the new project wizard complaining about 1.4?

Comment: It looks like Eclipse does not recognize the 'java-8-oracle' JRE/JDK and is defaulting to 1.4. Is this Eclipse 4.4 Luna? Earlier versions of Eclipse will not recognize Java 1.8

Comment: No, this is Kepler, but so far I have been able to use it with Java 8. Apart from these messages I am able to compile and run projects without issue. I will try to install Java 7 to see if it changes anything.

Comment: What do you have in the **Java** > **Installed JREs** section of your preferences?

Comment: I installed Java 7 (OpenJDK), add it as default JRE and now these warning messages are gone. Greg, if you wish to file an answer I will be glad to accept it.